# How to include an entity in all view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my new SF2 project, there is a list of entities I have to include in all views, because this list is used in my layout.

How can I do it without write a query selection in all my controllers and give it to my view?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know, if this is the best solution, but you can create an action for this and in your layout

```
{% render "AcmeBundle:AcmeController:list" %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers